# Is there a python function which will separate numerical and categorical variables as separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

If a DataFrame Column has numerical and categorical variables I want to separate them into two different columns with numerical values in one column and categorical values in other column as given below.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col":['a', '1', 'b', '2', '3', 'c', 'd' ,'e']})
```

[image: Image showing numerical and categorical values separately.]

I wrote a function which will do exactly as i want for a list but i am unable to apply the function for dataframe columns like how get_dummies does.
"pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['A', 'D'], columns=['A', 'D'])"

[image: Image showing my code].

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please hava a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "Prints(df)" prints are not going to work.Is there any solution without prints?

Comment: Ye there is a solution. Just read the link I shared and see how can you share code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you happy to have `nan` in your numerical column? In this case you can use
`pd.to_numeric` and `np.where` to achieve your goal.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col":['a', '1', 'b', '2', '3', 'c', 'd' ,'e']})

df[0] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
df[1] = np.where(
    df[0].isnull(),
    df['col'],
    '')
```

and the output is

```bash
  col    0  1
0   a  NaN  a
1   1  1.0   
2   b  NaN  b
3   2  2.0   
4   3  3.0   
5   c  NaN  c
6   d  NaN  d
7   e  NaN  e
```

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

use regex (need change pattern if numeric values are not only integer)

```
df['col'].str.extract('(^\d+$)?(.+)?').fillna('')
```

out:

```
    0   1
0       a
1   1   
2       b
3   2   
4   3   
5       c
6       d
7       e
```

If you don't want to use regex, use boolean masking.

```
cond = df['col'].str.isdigit()
pd.DataFrame([df['col'].where(cond, ''), df['col'].where(~cond, '')]).T
```

same result

Comment: Can you write the same regex code for multiple columns?

Comment: @nasrinbegumpathan Your request is not clear, so I cannot perform it. Most problems described in words are not clear. so we make minimal and reproducible example.  And If you want to ask a separate question, at first select the answer to the previous question for other people.

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = df['col'].str.isnumeric()
df['numbers'] = df.loc[numbers, 'col']
df['categories'] = df.loc[~numbers, 'col']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col numbers categories
0   a     NaN          a
1   1       1        NaN
2   b     NaN          b
3   2       2        NaN
4   3       3        NaN
5   c     NaN          c
6   d     NaN          d
7   e     NaN          e
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `.pivot`:

```py
print(
    df.assign(i=(~df["col"].str.isnumeric()).astype(int))
    .pivot(columns="i", values="col")
    .fillna("")
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Prints:

```
   0  1
0     a
1  1   
2     b
3  2   
4  3   
5     c
6     d
7     e
```